# Passing variable from JS and using it in PHP isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, html, shopping-cart

I'm working on onlineshop.php page that is supposed to first ask the user about the name of his shopping cart, this is done using java script's prompt..

i will paste the code to you and explain the problem clearly

first this is the js code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter Cart Name");

    document.getElementById("person").value=person;
    document.getElementById("form").submit();

   // if (person != null) {
   //     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
     //   "Your Cart Name is " + person;
    //}
}
```

it asks the user to enter his shopping cart name. Then, there are many products in the page, each product has its own form to add to the shopping cart. this is the form's code:

```
<form id='form' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' style='display:inline;'  >

   <figure>
  <img src='eye.jpg'  alt='The Pulpit Rock' width='130' height='130' style='left:00px;top:00px; '>
  <figcaption style='text-align:center;'><b>".$info['Pro_Name']."</b><br/>".$info['Price']."<p style='color:green;'>".$info['Availability']."</p><p style='font-size:13px;display:inline'>Quantity:</p>
  <input type='number' name='quantity' min='1' max='10' style='width:3em;'></figcaption>
</figure>

<input type='hidden' name='Pro_ID' value=".$info['Pro_ID']." />
<input type='hidden' name='Price' value=".$info['Price']." />
<input type='hidden' name='Pro_Name' value='".$info['Pro_Name']."' />
<input type='hidden' name='Availability' value='".$info['Availability']."' />
<input type='hidden' id='person' name='cart_Name' />


<input name='button1' type='submit' value='Add To Cart' style='width:8em;   ' />

</form>
```

I tried to make the variable **person** hidden so that i can use it in the query up, to insert the cart name to the database.

and here is the query:

```
if ( isset($_POST['Pro_ID'], $_POST['Price'] , $_POST['Pro_Name'] ) ) {
    $qry="INSERT INTO shopping_cart(Cart_Name,Pro_Name,Pro_ID,Price) VALUES ( '".$_POST['person']."','".$_POST['Pro_Name']."',".$_POST['Pro_ID'].",".$_POST['Price'].")";
                $result = mysql_query ($qry );

            }
```

The error i get when i click on **add to cart** :

```
Notice: Undefined index: person in C:\xampp\htdocs\sw\onlineshop.php on line 9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spot the differences:

```
document.getElementById("person").value=person;
                         ^^^^^^--- your ID

<input type='hidden' id='person' name='cart_Name' />
          your ID ---^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^---what gets submitted to the server
```

You want want `$_POST['cart_Name']`. The JS-side variable names/IDs are utterly irrelevant when it comes time to submit the form. Only the `name` is used.

And note that you're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). please sit back and relax. Your server will be pwn3d very soon, rendering your problem moot.

Comment: Thank you very muck, problem solved.. but now i have a little problem that when i press add to cart the first time, it gets added successfully, but the second item i add to the cart i get the field cart_Name in the database empty! i think i have to enter it in the prompt message again but i want to enter it only once and that value gets stored for all items i add

Comment: Could u please explain what to you mean? i thought of defining a variable in the php part that **only** gets assigned once, will try it now hope it works

Comment: didn't work because there is a problem in **how** the variable can be assigned only once, if i put $flag variable it's value will keep getting updated whenever i run the code

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute should be person, if you want use that as an index in a POST operation.

Given the way your code is now, the index name in the query should be "cart_name"